# Dual Citizen UK Australia, Entering UK on OZ passport to avoid possible UK arrest warrant

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, australian-citizens

My first post here and its a tricky situation.
Basically  I need to know if I enter the UK on my Australian passport (I have done this before with no problems) will the authorities know about any arrest warrant out for me issued in UK?
I might add that the possible charges relate to a very messy divorce, vindictive ex and possibly maintenance arrears.

Not serious but I have been overseas for several years and don't know what to expect. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I guess you could check Interpol for your name and see what that says: http://www.interpol.int/notice/search/wanted

Comment: Thanks, but isn't Interpol for serious international crimes?

Comment: Looking at a random sampling of people listed on it it looks like they're all listed for murder. So you might be right. idk...  doesn't mean you can't search for your name. I searched for mine, not that I found anything.

Comment: Just searched and im not on there thankfully

Comment: In your shoes I'd hire a UK lawyer to resolve the warrant and related issues before ever setting foot back in the UK. You'll be in a much weaker position if you land and are arrested.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds dodgy, frankly.

As far as I know, the border control system is not connected to PNC (police system where "wanted" flags are set for people, among other things) directly.

That said, UK is one of the countries requiring API (advanced passenger info) from airlines, therefore the airline that you are flying with will pass your details (specifically, name, date of birth and passport details, along with possibly some other info) to UK government.  I don't know which exact systems this info will then be matched against, but if it is matched against PNC, then it'll likely be a positive match, as the PNC doesn't care about the citizenship info, only name+dob.

On the whole, if there is an arrest warrant out for you, you should count on the worst.  Police loves these warrants, as they don't need to search for people - simply meet them at the arrival gate.

Comment: It sounds dodgy I know but I am probably being over careful. Just don't like suprises.

Comment: Perhaps I can find out if a warrant is issued?

Comment: @monkey Ideally, you would find this out, but I don't quite know how.

Comment: Or perhaps fly into Europe and then cross into UK. I know that last time I did that they didn't even look at passports as long as you waved a UK one. Maybe its got stricter.

Comment: Maybe I can just ask my mate in UK. Hes a copper

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware if you have a Uk warrant of arrest, it doesnt also mean that you have an EUW, EUW are only issued if the fellon is suspected to be in the EU (proof to the judge must be shown or good cause to beleive) and even then it has to be a serious crime as it involves alot of paper work, some countries like spain ive been told generaly dont care to much about them, hence criminals go to spain

Answer (score -4):

You will def be arrested when you land in uk AND any EU country as all are sharing the law enforcement data bases.You will be detained and sent back back to UK if you get arrested in the continent of Europe and if you land in UK you be be detained,Taken to the custody suite at the Airport and then taken in the custody of the police station of where the charges are issued.Bail may be refused or granted within a couple of hours after arriving at the police station.If bail is refused then you will have a court appearance within 24 hours and another shot at bail.If bail is refused again then you will be held for a few days until you are taken to a category b prison and held on remand until the court and verdict and sentence are done.

Comment: Can you provide evidence of this, or links to help out the OP?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Arrest_Warrant

Comment: EAWs are only issued when requested and for certain categories of crime, mostly fairly serious ones, so it's unlikely the OP has been issued one even if he has a UK arrest warrant.

Comment: FYI no Eu warrant is needed for return of a fugitive back to UK as the shared Lea information will flag a fugitive regardless of a warrant,So the moment the perp presents a document of travel all relevant warrants etc will automatically show up and the the relevant UK authorities will be contacted will progress forward from that point.People have been sent to other EU countries on as little as an outstanding non payment of a meal so he would not want to be settling into an unrealistic comfort zone thinking all is well.

Comment: In fact EAW practice depends hugely on the country. Poland issues them for nearly everything (and, last time I heard about this, accounted for about half of all EAW), other countries not so much. But you can't assume that every arrest warrant is reported to other EU countries.

Comment: I don't know what your background is but I have good rapor with most government and lea so My information is pretty much on target,I can assure you in this era of isis etc all   relevant government bodies have real time data matching so its pretty much a cake walk that it will show.   Any way I feel this perp should front up and sort this out that as this is the only way forward from the shadows as this account of his offence is minor in today's global era.

Comment: I never reall saw myself as an international fugitive for not paying my ex all that she has demanded. Must be millions of us in the same situation and that being tha case the authorities must be drained of resources addressing the issue. My worry was if it had gone through the courts which knowing my ex it is most likely and then perhaps the court then criminalize it and issue warrants etc. I don't really know but from what I have been told by my police friend in UK I have no warrants out for me in UK so I should be all good.

Comment: Prof Dakari, you info is BS. but thanks for the input